# What is the accuracy of the areasOfInterest property for a CLPlacemark object?

Tags: ios, apple-maps, clplacemark

I noticed that when reverse geocoding location (latitude/longitude to CLPlacemark), the placemark(s) that are returned have an areasOfInterest String array property.

Is the list ordered by closest/most accurate areas of interest? What other details should be known about this property if you were to use it?